# Difference between golang pointers

Tags: pointers, go, struct, interface, formatting

There are 2 kinds of variables that I have. Check for the [Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ojjzqbFEJ7), and I don't understand why this is happening. The problem: what I get from the `Models` it should be a `struct` to use it for GORM `First()` function.

The code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Test struct {
    Test string
}

var Models = map[string]interface{}{
    "test": newTest(),
}

func main() {
    test1 := Test{}
    fmt.Println("Test 1: ")
    fmt.Printf("%v", test1)
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println("Test 1 as pointer: ")
    fmt.Printf("%v", &test1)
    fmt.Println()
    test2 := Models["test"]
    fmt.Println("Test 2: ")
    fmt.Printf("%v", test2)
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println("Test 2 as pointer: ")
    fmt.Printf("%v", &test2)

}

func newTest() Test {
    var model Test 
    return model
}
```

Comment: You should paste the code here. and in brief, `test1` has type of `Test`, and `test2` has type of `interface{}` (a.k.a empty interface). it's a different type.

Comment: @ymonad Yes, I checked it, but how can I return it ad the correct struct?

Comment: Of course you can change `map[string]interface{}` to `map[string]Test`. However I suppose that this is [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Do you have any specific problem you want to solve ?

Comment: @ymonad the Models array is full of with structs and i alwys want to return the instance of the correct struct. For example there is 300 struct which all represent database tables and i always want to return an instance of the table what i want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** In the first case you pass a value of type `*Test` for printing, but in the second case you pass a value of type `*interface{}`! The `%v` verb means to format using the default formatting, but the default formatting depends on the type of the value.

---

The difference you see is just the default formatting rules of the [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) package's implementation.

You're using [`fmt.Printf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Printf):

```
func Printf(format string, a ...interface{}) (n int, err error)
```

which takes a format string and other arguments as type `interface{}`. So note that if the value you pass is not of type `interface{}`, the value will be wrapped in a value of type `interface{}`.

Now let's see your examples:

```
test1 := Test{}
// ...
fmt.Printf("%v", &test1)
```

`test1` is of type `Test`, and you pass `&test1` which is of type `*Test`. This will be wrapped in an `interface{}`. The formatting rules from the package doc of `fmt`:

> For compound objects, the elements are printed using these rules, recursively, laid out like this:
>
> ```
> struct:             {field0 field1 ...}
> array, slice:       [elem0 elem1 ...]
> maps:               map[key1:value1 key2:value2]
> pointer to above:   &{}, &[], &map[]
> ```

Since it is a pointer to a `struct`, the `&{}` format will be used. `Test` has a field `Test string`, but you didn't set its value, so it defaults to the [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) of the type `string` which is the empty string `""`. That's why you see nothing when displayed. Note that if you would have initialized it like this:

```
test1 := Test{"a"}
```

The output would have been:

```
&{a}
```

Let's see your 2nd example:

```
test2 := Models["test"]
// ...
fmt.Printf("%v", &test2)
```

The first line is a [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations), type of `test2` will be inferred from the right-hand side expression. The right hand side expression is an [index expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions), indexing a map. Its type will be the value type of the map, and since type of `Models` is `map[string]interface{}`, type of `test2` will be `interface{}`.

So far so good. But what happens when you try to print it like `fmt.Printf("%v", &test2)`? You pass a pointer to `test2` which is of type `interface{}`, so what you pass is of type `*interface{}`, and since this is not identical to `interface{}`, it will be wrapped in another `interface{}` value.

So what gets passed to `fmt.Printf()` is an `interface{}` value, wrapping a `*interface{}` value being the address of the `test2` variable.

And now the formatting rule that applies here:

> The default format for %v is:
>
> ```
> bool:                    %t
> int, int8 etc.:          %d
> uint, uint8 etc.:        %d, %x if printed with %#v
> float32, complex64, etc: %g
> string:                  %s
> chan:                    %p
> pointer:                 %p
> ```

Since the value to be formatted is a pointer (`*interface{}`), `%v` will default to `%p`, which is:

> Pointer:
>
> ```
> %p    base 16 notation, with leading 0x
> ```

So the result is properly printing the address value in hexadecimal format, e.g.:

```
0x1040a160
```

---

To obtain a struct from `test2`, you can use [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions). So it should rather be something like this:

```
t2 := Models["test"]
test2 := t2.(Test) // test2 is of type Test
```

This `test2` has identical type to that of `test1`, and will produce the same result when printing. Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ndSvevmGJ9).

Best would be though to store `*Test` values in the map, and so no type assertion or even storing in local variable would be necessary, as the `interface{}` stored in the map would already be a pointer to `Test`, which can be used / passed around as-is.

Comment: Nice answer, and mostly I discovered this, but currently I don't have solution to my problem: I wrote my problem above what is your advice? _"the Models array is full of with structs and i alwys want to return the instance of the correct struct. For example there is 300 struct which all represent database tables and i always want to return an instance of the table what i want to use"_

Comment: @PumpkinSeed I don't understand your example, maybe you should post that as a new question?

Comment: I taked it, I hope everything is understandable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038782/golang-database-manager-api-concept-error-with-type-assertion

Answer (score 1):

According to the **Size and alignment guarantees** as per golang docs

> A struct or array type has size zero if it contains no fields (or
>   elements, respectively) that have a size greater than zero. Two
>   distinct zero-size variables may have the same address in memory.

This is why  `Test 1` is `&{}`

> Interface values are represented as a two-word pair giving a pointer
>   to information about the type stored in the interface and a pointer to
>   the associated data.

`Test2` is an `interface{}`, Test2 thus has pointer to information about type stored and pointer to the data itself. It Type and Value informations