# How does a pointer to a struct or array value in Go work?

Tags: pointers, go, struct, reference

Considering the following Go struct:

```
type Person struct {
    Name    string
    Age     int
    Country string
}
```

I have encountered numerious times the following use:

```
p := &Person{"Adam", 33, "Argentina"}
```

Yet I can not see the point in pointing to a struct value, and I wonder, how does it differ from:

```
n := &999 // Error
```

My questions are:

1. How is it even possible to point to a value, even if it is a struct or array and not a primitive like a string or int? Strange enough, the following doesn't contribute to my understanding:

   ```
   fmt.Println(p, &p) // outputs: &{Adam 33 Argentina} 0xc042084018
   ```
2. Why would a programmer want to declare a struct instance by a pointer? What could you achieve doing so?

Answer (score 3):

`&Person{}` is a language "construct", it's part of the spec: it allocates a new variable of `Person` type, and provides you the address of that anonymous variable.

[Spec: Composite literals:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals)

> [Taking the address](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators) of a composite literal generates a pointer to a unique [variable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variables) initialized with the literal's value.

Also: [Spec: Variables:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variables)

> Calling the built-in function [new](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Allocation) or **taking the address of a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) allocates storage for a variable at run time**.

`&999` is not allowed by the language spec. The possible operands of the address operators are listed in the [Spec: Address operators:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators)

> The operand must be *addressable*, that is, either a variable, pointer indirection, or slice indexing operation; or a field selector of an addressable struct operand; or an array indexing operation of an addressable array. As an exception to the addressability requirement, `x` may also be a (possibly parenthesized) [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals).

`p := Person{}` creates a new variable `p` whose type will be `Person`. `p := &Person{}` creates a new variable whose type will be `*Person`.

See possible duplicate: [How do I do a literal *int64 in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30716354/how-do-i-do-a-literal-int64-in-go/30716481#30716481)

When you print the values with the [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) package, it has certain rules how to print values of different types:

> For compound objects, the elements are printed using these rules, recursively, laid out like this:
>
> ```
> struct:             {field0 field1 ...}
> array, slice:       [elem0 elem1 ...]
> maps:               map[key1:value1 key2:value2]
> pointer to above:   &{}, &[], &map[]
> ```

When you use `fmt.Println()`, the default formatting rules will be applied, which for a value of type `*int` is the `%p` verb, which will print the memory address in hexadecimal format, but for a pointer to struct it prints the struct value prepended with an `&` sign (`&{}`). You can read more about it in related question: [Difference between golang pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42039827/difference-between-golang-pointers/42042673#42042673)

If you want to print the pointed value, dereference the pointer and pass the pointed value, e.g.:

```
var p = new(int)
*p = 12
fmt.Println(*p) // Prints 12
```

As to why to create a pointer to a value (and not a value), see these related questions:

[Pointers vs. values in parameters and return values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542989/pointers-vs-values-in-parameters-and-return-values)

[Why should constructor of Go return address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31932822/why-should-constructor-of-go-return-address)

[Go, X does not implement Y (... method has a pointer receiver)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40823315/go-x-does-not-implement-y-method-has-a-pointer-receiver)