# What's the difference between struct pointer and integer pointer output?

Tags: pointers, go

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Employee struct {
    ID int
    Name string
}

func main(){
    var zhexiao Employee
    zhexiao.Name = "xiao"
    fmt.Println(&zhexiao)

    x := 1
    p := &x
    fmt.Println(p)
}
```

The above code outputs two kinds of pointers.

1. struct pointer output is: `&{0 xiao}`
2. integer pointer output is: `0xc0420600b0` (it looks like a memory address)

Why struct pointer output is not a memory address? If it's not memory address, what is it?

Thanks a lot
Zhe

Comment: fmt.Println is not suitable to inspect the internals. Read the language spec.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [How does a pointer to a struct or array value in Go work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51018357/how-does-a-pointer-to-a-struct-or-array-value-in-go-work/51018395#51018395); and [Difference between golang pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42039827/difference-between-golang-pointers/42042673#42042673).

Answer (score 7):

It depends on how you look at it. You are implicitly using the package `fmt` default print verb (`%v`). Here are some other ways to look at it by explicitly using other print verbs.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Employee struct {
    ID   int
    Name string
}

func main() {
    var zhexiao Employee
    zhexiao.Name = "xiao"
    fmt.Printf("%[1]v %[1]p\n", &zhexiao)

    x := 1
    fmt.Printf("%[1]v %[2]p\n", x, &x)
    p := &x
    fmt.Printf("%[1]v %[1]p\n", p)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/4dV8HtiS8rP

Output:

```
&{0 xiao} 0x1040a0d0
1 0x1041402c
0x1041402c 0x1041402c
```

---

Reference: [Package fmt: Printing](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/)

Comment: Dear, Thanks a lot. It confused me for a long time. But now i got it. LOL. Thanks again.